# What's BLUE from CCP Stackless presentations?

Tags: python, stackless

In [Stackless Python in Eve](http://www.slideshare.net/Arbow/stackless-python-in-eve), there is some talk about "BLUE" objects in Python.
Does anyone know details about this technology?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a codename for a framework [CCP](http://www.ccpgames.com) probably developed internally for [EVE Online](http://www.eveonline.com). EVE Online installations come with `blue.dll`. There is a python API to it (`import blue`).

Digging into `blue.dll` reveals:

Description: CCP Blue Framework

```
$ strings blue.dll | egrep "python|Py" | less
BlueObjectBuilderPython
BlueEventToPython
IBluePyOS
IPythonEvents
IPythonMethods
IPythonNumeric
PythonEvents
BlueEventToPython
BlueObjectBuilderPython
Proxy object builder that calls a python method to construct the object.
BeOS::Python
BlueOS/mShutdownPythonCallbacks
Py_FatalError: %s
Fatal Python error: %s
PumpOS::end PumpPython
s|O:PyCreateInstance
Thunker for constructing python objects.
python file object api
Python object
Python object pointer
An unrepresentable Python object
PyOS::StacklessIoDispatch
PyOS::Run Watchdog
PyOS::Create Tasklet
PyOS::PyError
PyOS::Synchro Tick
Python Logs
Runs a python script.
Enable python ref. stack trace
Returns the python and blue reference counts
Error while calling Python logging callback function. Disabling logging in Python!
BluePyOS
BluePyOS/mThreads
```

Comment: Interesting. BeOS::Python? It's sad that BeOS didn't take off. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I guess it's all I can get.